# UITableViewCell will not work with UIColor colorWithRed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor, uibackgroundcolor

I have an iOS app with a table view. One problem I am having is that I cannot set the cell background colour with a custom RGB colour.

For example, this will work:

```
// Set the background colour.
[cell contentView].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

However this on the other hand will not work:

```
// Set the background colour.
[cell contentView].backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(54/255.0) green:(215/255.0) blue:(183/255.0) alpha:1.0];
```

I don't get why its so darn hard to just set one blumming background colour!... :(

I am really frustrated about this because I have tried quite a few different approaches including:

- Adding a custom `UIView` to the background of my cell and setting its background colour.
- Have tried setting this property in the `willDisplayCell` method.
- Have tried both the `cell.backgroundColor` and `cell.contentView` and neither will work.

Does the `UITableView` not support custom RGB colours or something?

Comment: Does the color not change or is it black?

Comment: @WMios It always ends up red for some reason when I am using a custom RGB colour :(

Comment: Try changing it to [UIColor greenColor]. Does it stay red?

Comment: @WMios I tried that and it turns green which is great and all.... but I want to use my own custom RGB values as stated in my question.

Comment: Yeah I understand your question, I was trying to see if you were setting the value again later.

Comment: Have you just tried doing `UIColor *custom = //your color settings;` and then assigning it the value of `custom`?

Comment: Also, what kind of red are you seeing? Is it the same as if Red = 1, Green = 0, and Blue = 0?

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but try appending ".0" to 54, 215, and 183.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam, while that was my first thought (as evident by my first question) it would be black instead of red, right?

Comment: @WMios No this is not a duplicate as stated in my question.

Comment: @WMios Also I tried your other solution.... I guess the only way for me is to define my UIColors in the ```cellForRowAtIndexPath``` method.......

Comment: Ok, so will you answer my question about which red you see?

Comment: @WMios I tried Red 1, Green 0 and Blue 0 and it comes out as black which is odd.

Comment: I had meant which color does it look like when it shows red. Is it 100% red, or is it slightly dark?

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but for some reason it worked for me when I had this issue randomly, try changing the numbers to be decimals instead of doing the math inside the parameter. So if it was 25.5/255, instead of putting that, put .1. For some reason, this fixed it for me when I had the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried creating a UIColor object with the right values as a member in the implementation you are in  (I assume a view controller or something like it) and to assign this to the cell background color instead of creating a new [UIColor object] every time you need it? This would obviously also save a little bit of memory as your custom color object doesn't get generated every time it is assigned as it is in your example. [UIColor redColor] IIRC just returns a reference to a ready made object, so it is somewhat different in this regard.

Comment: I tried it here, it is working fine for me.

Just make sure that you have removed the line which sets the background color as red.